# SQL Server - Select INTO statement stored in sys.tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know how to find the CREATE statement for a table in SQL Server but is there any place that stores the actual SQL code if I use SELECT INTO ... to create a table and if so how do I access it?

Comment: The schema of the new table will match the schema of the Source table. you can check sys.tables catalogue view to see the definition of source table.

Comment: I feel like there may be more to this question... you seem to want the `create table mytable(...)` code that you can find by, for example, right clicking and selecting `script table as...` for something later on. Is this the case or are you merely trying to find the column datatypes as noted by @M.Ali

Comment: @scsimon : yes - I don't care about the variable types as much as I care about the underlying tables / code.  I'm in an environment with no SVN and I'm struggling to manage different versions of the same table and was wondering if the info is being stored somewhere by SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of creating tables with SELECT INTO.
First: You know the Schema, then you can declare a @Table Variable and perform the Select INSERT

Second: You can create a temp table:
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM Customer

There are some limitations on the second choice: 
 - You need to drop the temp table afterwards.
 - If there is a VARCHAR Column and the maximum number of characters of that given SELECT is 123 characters (example), and then you try to insert into the TEMP table afterwards with a greater number of characters, it will throw an error.

My recommendation is always declare a table in order to use, it makes it clear what is the intentions and increases readability.

Comment: Why would you need a `temp table` or `table variable` when the OP wanted to know how to create a table with a `SELECT INTO`? These steps are unnecessary since creating an actual table with this method is the same as you have created a `temp table`. Just remove the `temp table` step all together, or is there some other benefit to this you are trying to stress?